# How to reshape tensor flattened to a LSTM?

Tags: python, keras

Here I have some problems on coding in Keras. I need to process two sequential inputs with two types of embeddings, one is word embedding, the other is doc2vec embedding, both are `dim=300`. Then I am going to concatenate these two vectors into one longer vector since I want to obtain some stacked features from them. However these two embeddings could be in different spaces, so I have to map these two vectors into the same one with `nn.flatten()`. Then I need to feed the output vectors from flatten to a LSTM model. But the compiler complains that `Input 0 is incompatible with lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`, I never set the `ndim=3` at all and I don't know how to reshape the vectors as the new inputs with correct shapes.
Please help on the issue.

```
n_hidden = 50

batch_size = 64

def classification_softmax(left, right):
''' Helper function for the similarity estimate of the LSTMs outputs'''
return K.abs(left - right)
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(embeddings), 300, weights=[embeddings], input_length=max_seq_length,
                            trainable=False)


embedding_cfg_layer =  Embedding(len(cfg_embedding_matrix), 300, weights=[cfg_embedding_matrix], input_length=1,
                            trainable=False)


#cfg_embedding_l=krs.layers.Flatten()(embedding_cfg_layer(cfg_left_input))
#cfg_embedding_r=krs.layers.Flatten()(embedding_cfg_layer(cfg_right_input))
#encoded_left = krs.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([krs.layers.Flatten()(embedding_layer(left_input)),cfg_embedding_l])
#encoded_right = krs.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([krs.layers.Flatten()(embedding_layer(right_input)), cfg_embedding_r])

encoded_left = encoded_left
encoded_right = encoded_right
# Since this is a siamese network, both sides share the same LSTM
shared_lstm = LSTM(n_hidden,return_sequences=True)

#encoded_left=krs.layers.Reshape((2,))(encoded_left)
#encoded_right=krs.layers.Reshape((2,))(encoded_right)
left_output = shared_lstm(encoded_left)
right_output = shared_lstm(encoded_right)
    cfg_embedding_l=embedding_cfg_layer(cfg_left_input)
cfg_embedding_r=embedding_cfg_layer(cfg_right_input)
encoded_left = krs.layers.Concatenate(axis=0)([(embedding_layer(left_input),cfg_embedding_l])
encoded_right = krs.layers.Concatenate(axis=0)(embedding_layer(right_input), cfg_embedding_r])
...   
dist = Lambda(lambda x: classification_softmax(x[0], x[1]))([left_output, right_output])
classify = Dense(5, activation=softMaxAxis1)(dist)
# Pack it all up into a model
malstm = Model([left_input, right_input,cfg_left_input,cfg_right_input], [classify])

optimizer = Adadelta(clipnorm=gradient_clipping_norm)

# malstm.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy', f1, recall,precision])
malstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
[categorical_accuracy])#, f1, recall, precision])

# Start training
training_start_time = time()

malstm_trained = malstm.fit(
[X_train['left'], X_train['right'], X_train['cfg_A'], X_train['cfg_B']],
krs.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 5),
batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=n_epoch,
#callbacks=[metrics],
validation_data=(
    [X_validation['left'], X_validation['right'], 
X_validation['cfg_A'],X_validation['cfg_B']],
    krs.utils.to_categorical(Y_validation, 5)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell the exact shapes of your inputs from your example code so I can't give you an answer with exact shapes, but in this case you should use a `Reshape` layer.

I'm going to make the logical leap that your shape will be `(batch_size, 300 * max_seq_length  + 300)`, since the first `Embedding` layer outputs a `(max_seq_length, 300)` tensor, and the second outputs a `(1, 300)` tensor, and you flatten and concatenate them.

You want to reshape your 2D `(batch_size, 300 * max_seq_length  + 300)` to a 3D shape like `(batch_size, 300 * max_seq_length  + 300, 1)`. Add a `Reshape` layer with your target shape:

```
reshape = keras.layers.Reshape(300 * max_seq_length + 300, 1)

encoded_left = reshape(encoded_left)
encoded_right = reshape(encoded_right)
```

And then pass those into your LSTM.

Comment: @ Primusa Many thanks for your answer, it looks correct.I tried your solution then I got another runtime error: "expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape(24000,5)". 24000 is the length of list Y_validation in the form of one-hot array.     classify = Dense(5, activation=softMaxAxis1)(dist)  can see I would like to classify the data into 5 classes. So I have Y_value in list like[0,1,2,3,4....] and I use keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_validation,5) to obtain one-hot matrix as Y. Someone said I need to set LSTM(hidden,return_Sequences=False), but it got out of memories.

Comment: What is the shape of a single sample in your output?

Comment: you mean to the prediction value  Y right ? it is  Y_value in list like[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[0],[0],....], which just is one number [0,4] representing one  class. the numbers store in a list as Y_value and I pass the list to the function keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_validation,5). The input sample contains two parts: one sentence(the max length is 1000, e.g.) and a graph representation. Both of them are input through input layer.I update the code snippet to see the context

Comment: Please just post your full model and some dummy input and output data (not actual data, fake data of the same shape i.e. `np.random.rand(10, 32, 300)`). I'll be able to help you better that way.

Comment: I updated the code in the post. I am trying to print shape of inputs and outs for the sample. However I found the mistake I could make in the model: batch*max_length* dimension =64(batch)*24000(max_length)*300 in flattened vector that  it could be too large to compute. I might need to concatenate two parts after LSTM

Comment: `Model([left_input, right_input,cfg_left_input,cfg_right_input], [classify])`. What are the shapes of these inputs and the output? Note that you can use `model.summary()` to print am overview of your model.

Comment: left_input=right_input=[batch_size,maxlength,dim=300];cfg_left_input=rcfg_right_input=[1,], cfg_(sides) are only an index number for retrieval of embedding vector from cfg_embedding_table, which I want to concatenate with (sides)_input after LSTM, it should make sense. ;Yes, I can use summary(). and are you sure you are a high school student ? ：）

Comment: Yeah I'm in high school. At the moment does your concatenation work? If not, what is the error being thrown?

Comment: I changed the code of model part then now there is no any complains from compiler. The code is working. But I need to wait for the result to see if concatenation  positively affects the model. I updated the code in post again

Comment: and I change the concatenation setting from 0 to 1 (axis=1)